# How to know user-agent information for metasploit modules

Tags: metasploit

I want to know the user-agent compatibility information for

"./windows/browser/ms13_090_cardspacesigninhelper.rb" module in backtrack.

Kindly let me know how can I get this information.

I searched in web and found  "use auxiliary" command can give this info but for this module I am not able run this command.

Thanks,
Rajul

Answer (score 0):

First of All,

Use Auxiliary command is to load Auxiliary Modules.

And, if the module is based on a web attack then you may find this information by issuing-

> show advanced

command. But only after you load a particular module